# RecyclerView snap scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html) In my RecyclerView to mimic ViewPager's scrolling behavior.

However, when using smoothScrollToPosition with my recyclerview I'm still getting the ugly animation. Looking at the code it seems that recycler view uses the layout manager for that instead of the ViewFlinger

Does anyone know how can I make it use the view flinger with smoothScrollToPosition, so I can change pages nicely?

Comment: Have you tried extending the RecyclerView and overriding `smoothScrollToPosition()`?

Comment: refer this link https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Yes, but I wasn't able to call the SnapHelper scroller as it's private

Comment: @pankajkhedekar Thanks, but I can't see how this is helpful for my problem

Comment: u can refer that source code and implement the same alternatively.